# Twitch api freecodecamp loop issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, xmlhttprequest, twitch

I am trying to complete the twitch api at freecodecamp.

I have an allTotalUsers array with the users I am looping through.

My loop appears to grabbing the info I need for each user in my allTotalUsers list correctly.
I tested this by displaying data from the offline users and it showed(multiple).

The issue is on my if(streamInfo==null) statement, the streamerName is showing duplicates only.

For example, If there is 2 offline users, Bob and John.

It will show
Bob
Bob

```
function showOfflineUsers() {

var onlinePeople = $('#displayInfo');
onlinePeople.html('');

//allTotalUsers is an array list that is loaded when the page loads and stored globally.
for (var i = 0; i < allTotalUsers.length; i++) {

    var streamerName = allTotalUsers[i];
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            // gets the status of stream(null etc)
            var streamInfo = json['stream'];

            if (streamInfo == null) {
                onlinePeople.append("<li>" + "<a href = 'https://www.twitch.tv/" + streamerName + "'>" + streamerName + "</a>" + "</li>" + "<br>");

            }


        }

    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamerName + "?client_id=" + clientId, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

};
}
```

Comment: Replace `var streamerName = allTotalUsers[i];` with `let streamerName = allTotalUsers[i];`

Comment: that made it work...about 15 hours of this and thats what it took lol. I have to read up on let vs var now, I had zero clue.

Answer (score 2):

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations)

> **let** and const declarations define variables that **are scoped to the
>   running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment**. The variables are
>   created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but
>   may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s LexicalBinding is
>   evaluated.

So, as opposed to `var` which is scoped to `VariableEnvironment` (of execution's context), `let` is scoped to `LexicalEnvironment`.

Replace

```
var streamerName = allTotalUsers[i];
```

with

```
let streamerName = allTotalUsers[i];
```

Comment: @born2gamble Glad it worked for you. Please don't forget to upvote and accept if this answer has helped you.